# for each function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a toggle function which i have working fine, only i cant get it to work for each element on the page.

my current function is

```
$(".tog").click(function() {
                $("#shortinfo").toggle();
                $('#shortinfo').toggleClass('open');
                return false;
            })
```

ive tried

```
$(".tog").each.click(function() {
                $("#shortinfo").toggle();
                $('#shortinfo').toggleClass('open');
                return false;
            })
```

and

```
$(".tog").each (click(function() {
                $("#shortinfo").toggle();
                $('#shortinfo').toggleClass('open');
                return false;
```

---

I have an accordion similar too

```
<h1>title </h1>
<div class="shortcontent">asdasdasd</div>
<div class="longcopy">long stuff here</div>

<h1>title </h1>
<div class="shortcontent">asdasdasd</div>
<div class="longcopy">long stuff here</div>

<h1>title </h1>
<div class="shortcontent">asdasdasd</div>
<div class="longcopy">long stuff here</div>

<h1>title </h1>
<div class="shortcontent">asdasdasd</div>
<div class="longcopy">long stuff here</div>
```

the idea is when its clicked 'shortcontent' dissapears. at the moment that is only happening on the first section

Comment: your question isn't very clear.

Comment: I have an accordion, and i need it to work for each and at the moment its only working on my first div

Comment: First one should work, what do you mean you cant get it working for every element on the page? Might need to post some markup.

Comment: In your toggle you are specifying the toggle on an ID, so only the element with that ID will open.

Comment: If you post the HTML you will get a good answer

Comment: I don't see any element in your markup with the 'tog' class applied to it.

Comment: Nor any element with an ID of `shortinfo`...

Comment: Alice, your jQuery appears to relate to a completely different piece of markup than the one you've posted.  Can you clarify what you want to happen? Should the `shortcontent` be switched with the `longcopy` when it's clicked, and vice-versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that the question has changed...

You're using the wrong selector. First of all, `#shortinfo` is not the same as `.shortcontent`. Second, in order to make sure only the correct `.shortcontent` disappears, you need to use `.siblings()`.

If the `.tog` element is within each accordion...

```
$(".tog").click(function() {
                var $shortContent = $(this).siblings(".shortcontent");
                $shortContent.toggle();
                $shortContent.toggleClass('open');
                return false;
            });
```

If there is one `.tog` element and you want all `.shortcontent` to collapse...

```
$(".tog").click(function() {
                var $shortContent = $(".shortcontent");
                $shortContent.toggle();
                $shortContent.toggleClass('open');
                return false;
            });
```

This should hopefully be enough to get you started.

Comment: Also: Why doesn't the first version work? You need to post more information, because you can use `.click` on a jQuery object that encompasses multiple HTML elements.

Comment: @Martin B.: No, but the question title implied that he wanted to know how to use `.each` properly. I answered that and also mentioned that the `.each` shouldn't be needed. Please consider removing your downvote if you are the one who used it.

Comment: I don't think this is an issue with not understanding `.each()`. I think it's an issue with not understanding the basics of jQuery.

Comment: @Jack: Probably. I've been making a flurry of edits and now my answer should be useful.